# class "fa" for font Awesome

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

I'm using the latest version of Font Awesome and as it is clear all icons have their own classes. But my question is Why class "fa" should include as well (e.g. class="fa fa-wifi").

Answer (score 0):

**`fa`** is a common class for giving a style to every icon font, like `font-size`, `font-weight`, `font-style` etc.

Comment: why is it necessary to use prefix "fa" when "fa-home" is pretty clear?

Comment: if we remove first "fa" from class "fa fa-home" the style of the font will be remove from there